# formatting a log table in rows

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(){


//Numbers 1 - 10
cout << "Number" ;
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    cout << "\n" << i  ;
}//end for
cout << endl;



//log base 2
cout << "\n" << "Log base 2" << "\n";
for(int x = 1; x <= 10; x++){
cout<<log2(x)<<endl;
}//end for



//log base 10
cout << "\n" << " Log base 10 " << "\n" ;
for ( int y = 1; y <= 10; y++){
cout<<log10(y)<<endl;
}//end for


cout << "Log base e";
for (int z = 1; z <=10 ; z++){



}
}//end main
```

So i have to create a table of logs but im having trouble formatting them. Can someone help? But other than that everything is fine, everything compiles fine and it doesnt give any errors, but heres an example of what the table is supposed to be like

Number _______Log base 2 _______Log base 10_______ Log base e

1 ____________0.000____________ 0.000____________ 0.000

2 ____________1.000 ____________0.301____________ 0.693

Comment: `std::log` is the base e logarithm function.

Comment: As for your other question, look into [`std::setw`](https://devdocs.io/cpp/io/manip/setw)

Comment: Looks to me like you want 1 `for ( int y = 1; y <= 10; y++)` loop that repeats something like `cout  << i << ' ' << log2(i) << ' ' << log10(i) << '\n';`

Answer (score 1):

Here's the complete code to print the table. You can see the output live at: https://wandbox.org/permlink/KI98R333vH9vUCBk

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void print_header()
{
    std::cout << std::setw(20) << std::setfill('_') << std::left << "Number "
              << std::setw(20) << std::setfill('_') << std::left << "Log base 2 "
              << std::setw(20) << std::setfill('_') << std::left << "Log base 10 "
              << std::setw(20) << std::setfill(' ') << std::left << "Log base e " << std::endl;
}

void print_table(int num)
{
    std::cout << std::setw(20) << std::setfill('_') << std::left << num
              << std::setw(20) << std::setfill('_') << std::left << log2(num)
              << std::setw(20) << std::setfill('_') << std::left << log10(num)
              << std::setw(20) << std::setfill(' ') << std::left << log(num) << std::endl;
}



int main(){

    print_header();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        print_table(i);
    }//end for

}//end main
```

Output:

```
Number _____________Log base 2 _________Log base 10 ________Log base e          
1___________________0___________________0___________________0                   
2___________________1___________________0.30103_____________0.693147            
3___________________1.58496_____________0.477121____________1.09861             
4___________________2___________________0.60206_____________1.38629             
5___________________2.32193_____________0.69897_____________1.60944             
6___________________2.58496_____________0.778151____________1.79176             
7___________________2.80735_____________0.845098____________1.94591             
8___________________3___________________0.90309_____________2.07944             
9___________________3.16993_____________0.954243____________2.19722             
10__________________3.32193_____________1___________________2.30259
```